# Early 2015 MacBook Pro shuts down after disk decryption at login

Tags: mac, macbook

I'm having an issue with my MacBook shutting down consistently on login, after decryption. This is a weird one that started very recently, for apparently no reason that I can discern: I made no software or hardware changes, although I suppose it's possible an OS update applied that I wasn't paying attention to.

The MacBook boots up fine to the login screen. I enter my credentials, it runs the disk decryption (for what seems like a bit longer than it usually would), and then the screen goes black. If I press the power button again, then it boots up and repeats the same behavior.

I tried safe boot and the same issue occurred. Power adapter is connected and reflects the MacBook is charged (which corresponds to the battery indicator during login and decryption).

I'm fairly adept with using Macs, but I'm an idiot when it comes to troubleshooting and diagnosing them. Any ideas as to what could be going on here, or what I can do about it?

Comment: This is a long shot, but do you have another user that you could login to? I always create a second user, usually called 'admin' in case something goes hinky with my main user account.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. :(  The only thing I can think of is that I _believe_ there's a **root** user, but if I recall correctly, login from that account is disabled.

Comment: Correct. You get to it by doing `sudo su -` from your regular user account.